# Django: make all models user dependent?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I have many models for very different things. Now I have added user authentication with django-allauth. What I want to do is to make all models user dependent. I mean that only the user can see their own model data that they have stored. What is the best way to achieve this? Do I need to add a ForeignKey to each model I have?

model.py:

```
class images(models.Model):
    ...

class things(models.Model):
    ...

class devices(models.Model):
    ...

class messages(models.Model):
    ...

#and so on...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to add a `ForeignKey` to each model I have?

**Yes**, but you do not have to alter all models, you can work with an abstract base model:

```
from django.conf import settings

class OwnedModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and then use it in all subclasses:

```
class Image(OwnedModel, models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class Thing(OwnedModel, models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class Device(OwnedModel, models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class Message(OwnedModel, models.Model):
    # …
    pass
```

In your views you will have to filter on the user. On class-based views, you can probably do this easily with a mixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class OwnedMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            owner=self.request.user
        )

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This mixin can also be used for the `CreateView` and `UpdateView` to automatically set the owner for the created/updated objects.

then you can use these in `ListView`s, `DetailView`s, etc.:

```
class ImageListView(OwnedMixin, ListView):
    # …

class DeviceDetailView(OwnedMixin, DetailView):
    # …

class ThingCreateView(OwnedMixin, CreateView):
    # …
```